# jQuery submit not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

This jquery is working to submit a form in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox:

```
// Submit the form as long as there are no errors
                if (invalidFields.length == 0 || typeof invalidFields === 'undefined') {
                    $("form.sd_form").submit();
                }
```

It checks for some custom validation errors, and then it should submit the form if there are none (which it does, except in Firefox).

The function is wrapped in

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
```

I'm not sure what to try!

EDIT:
Here is a pastebin of the entire .js file. I'm really stuck here!
http://pastebin.com/UNKpU1tH

Comment: So what is different in Firefox? console.log() and see what is not working also checking to see if something is undefined but you read a property before hand looks like an error. If it is undefined, you would no be able to read its length.

Comment: Are you seeing javascript errors?  My guess is that invalidFields is undefined and Firefox is complaining about this invalidFields.length == 0 .  Try switching the order of those 2 tests, to make sure invalidFields is defined before checking it's value

Comment: The only error I see is "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead." but that's part of whole other plugin I'm using on Wordpress. I tried switching the tests, but no luck. I also tried `if (invalidFields == "undefined") {`

Comment: Here is the full .js file if that's helpful.
http://pastebin.com/UNKpU1tH

Comment: Just found a weird behavior. If I use Firefox's "inspect" tool and then click on the button (as if to inspect it) the form submits. ??